# Jquery: Change first word Color Span Issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change first color of define class or tag by using jquery. Things work fine but I have one title having own span and giving trouble. I am using below code to add span element and inline style for first word.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('.header-logo, h1').each(function() {
        var h = $(this).html();
        var index = h.indexOf(' ');
        if(index == -1) {
            index = h.length;
        }
        $(this).html('<span style="color:black;">' + h.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + h.substring(index, h.length));
    });

});
```

This is adding span tag perfectly and change the color too. But I have one title with below html structure

```
<h1>
    <span id="fav" class="btn-fav"><a href="#"Add to fav</a></span>
    <span class="the-title">Title text goes here</span>
</h1>
```

Here I want to add color only for "Title text goes here" first word (Title) but the javascript breaking structure by adding another span tag into the span tag something like below

```
<span style="color:black;">
<span< span=""> class="btn-fav id="fav">.....
```

So how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `html` method, `html` accepts a function, you can find the first word and wrap it by `span` element.

```
$('h1 .the-title').html(function(i, html){
   return html.replace(/(\w+\s)/, '<span class="black">$1</span>')
})​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AuKWT/

Note that you should fix your markup:

```
<span id="fav" class="btn-fav"><a href="#"Add to fav</a></span>
                                   ------^
```

---

```
$('.header-logo, h1').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), $title = $this.find('.the-title');
    if ($title.length) {
        $title.html(function(i,h) {
            return h.replace(/(\w+\s)/, '<span class="black">$1</span>')
        })
    } else {
        $this.html(function(i,h) {
            return h.replace(/(\w+\s)/, '<span class="black">$1</span>')
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: you mean adding another jquery function?

Comment: @pixelngrain If you want to select .the-title element, you can change your selector to `$('.header-logo, h1 .the-title')`.

Comment: Okay here my problem is using H1 for other purpose as well so when I am using this code it is removing black color from all H1 tag

Comment: @pixelngrain Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: It is almost there now one thing still remain is need to add color to "The Page Title" heading too

Comment: Your code is exactly what I want but why it is not working in my real files? I am just changing class according to my real class name. Just to make things simple I used simple class for demo code. Any idea?

Comment: @pixelngrain You might want to check developement tools console ( e.g. firebug console ) to see if there are any errors, then check if the classes are added. Also, you could try to place this in the code  `console.log( $('.header-logo, h1') );` to see if the elements you are targeting, actually exist in your html.

Comment: I have checked and everything seems fine. No error html entity is there. Just wonder why doesn't work here?

Comment: @pixelngrain Note that you haven't element with class of `the-title` in your posted fiddle. I had added it,     `<span class="">Item Title</span>`.

Comment: Wow its done. That was my stupid mistake. I am extremely sorry for that. everything was just fine but what changes the color that class I  haven't created. :P

It's just wonderful. Thanks a lot for great help :) answer selected and +1 thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to change the color of first occurance of any of specified class elements. For that you don't need to change the entire HTML

```
 $('.header-logo h1 ').find('.the-title').html(function(i, h){
    return h.replace(/\w+\s/, function(firstWord){
      return '<span style="color:Green;font-weight:bold">' + firstWord + '</span>';
    }); 
 });
```

Comment: `$(this).first().html('<span style="color:black;">' + h.substring(0, index) + '</span>' + h.substring(index, h.length));` I tried this but not working. I am not sure I am doing right or wrong. New to Jwuery

Comment: `    $('.heder-logo, h1').each(function() {
        var ele = $('.heder-logo, h1').first(), h = ele.html();
        var index = h.indexOf(' ');
        if(index == -1) {
            index = h.length;
        }
        ele.html('<span style="color:black">' + h.text() + '</span>');
    });` Still not getting. Am I doing right?

Comment: @pixelgrain Are you trying to change color of first `.the-title` in DOM?

Comment: Yes have a look this code I replied by @Undefined. This is what I am looking for just now need to change first word color for "The Page Title" too

Comment: @pixelngrain See my edit now.. It will change the first `the-title` color to black

Comment: It is adding color to entire title but not to the first word.

Comment: @pixelngrain The above edit will change the color of only first word :-)

Comment: Undefined answer works for me perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help and effort +1